# How can I scale/enlarge HTML content and save it as an image?

Tags: javascript, image, css, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I have a JavaScript product designer that allows the web page user to add text and images to create a dynamic promo product.  The design phase works great, and I use html2canvas to turn their custom product into an image.  The image looks great for the screen but is not suitable for printing, which is the ultimate goal.

How can I scale up HTML content (retaining the detail) and save the results as an image (png) ?

I have successfully scaled the image AFTER putting the web content on a canvas, but that clearly loses detail.

I have used the CSS3 "transform" property to scale my image BEFORE applying the content to the canvas.  That works and retains the detail and proportions nicely.  However, html2canvas ignores that CSS and exports the original size (as confirmed here: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/176 )

Anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: Thanks Ken, that link is interesting.  I think that could work for me if I design directly onto the canvas, as you suggested.  Perhaps that is the way to go, although with that approach will I still be able retain the identity of the individual text/image elements on the canvas?  I need to be able to tab through sub-elements in the designer and allow the user to alter them independently.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg your link is dead